# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, function is not async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I'm not sure why this is happening, I tried asycn/await, bluebrid, in-built promises, nothing works, this is my code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
const bar = require('./config/models/bar');

router.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
  getCollection('foo').then(data => res.sendStatus(200).json(data))
});

function getCollection() {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    bar.findAsync({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(result) //This prints the correct result to log
      resolve(result)
    })
  });
}
```

Whenever I go to `/foo` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: `return  new Promise(...` you need to return the promise. Also `getCollection()` is not accepting any argument, but that's probably just you posting. Next time you post, show the code how it actually is.

Comment: Other small note is you appear to be reading a really old blog or course. Mongoose functions all use promises right out of the box. No need to `promisifyAll()` on them. `mongoose.Promise = Promise` will use the bluebird library

Comment: Also note that findAsync should return a promise. You could replace the getCollection function body with something like `return bar.findAsync({}).then(function (result) { ... }).catch(function (err) { ... })`

Comment: @fardjad The point I was actually making is `return bar.find()` actually does that right out of the box.

Comment: @NeilLunn Oh that comment was for OP. And you're right; my point was he/she shouldn't pass a callback to a promisified function and doesn't need to create a new promise when the called function returns one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `Promise` from `getCollection`.

```
function getCollection() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    bar.findAsync({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(result) //This prints the correct result to log
      resolve(result)
    })
  });
}
```